# ASP.NET VB The operation has times out

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My project used visual studio 2010 and is a web service application project with VB. I add service referrence for the web service.

I'm having **the operations has times out** when i try to access third party web service with certificate in my production server (windows 2008 r2 standard). The certificate was not expired. I've already add the trust root cert and personal cert for local computer and current user. I have no problem with my UAT server but not production server. I open the web service URL in the production server successfully but it failed when try to connect with web service application.

Below code I used to add the certificate when calling web service.

```
Dim ws As New AService.AServiceService
Dim cert As New X509Certificate2("CERTIFICATE_NAME","PASSWORD")
ws.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)
```

Having error

```
An error occurred. Error: 
System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

Comment: Use Fiddler to see what is actually sent and received. You may be using the wrong URL, the other server may be too slow, your connection may be too slow.

Comment: what and how to use fiddler ><